# cakephp routing retrieve parameter from url to redirect

Tags: cakephp, routes

I am using cakephp v2.3.8 and struggle a bit with the routing.

The old url is www.domain.com/properties.aspx?prop=1999
I want to route this to the properties controller with id = 1999 so my url will look like:
www.domain.com/properties/view/1999

In my routes.php i strip the .aspx out of the url but struggle with this last bit.

```
Router::parseExtensions('htm','html','aspx');
```

This is how close I am:

```
Router::connect('/properties', array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view', ??? '));
```

This is the view function in the PropertiesController.php

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Property->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Sorry, we couldn\'t find what you were looking for...'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Property.' . $this->Property->primaryKey => $id));
    $propData = $this->Property->find('first', $options);
            $this->set('property', $propData);
}
```

This works perfect within the website, but not for those as mentioned, they are redirected to www.domain.com/properties

This is my .htaccess file in the public_html folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

### Thanks for looking into this.

File structure:

```
.htaccess [1]  
/app/.htaccess [2]  
/lib/Cake/  
/public_html/.htaccess [3]    
/plugins/  
/vendors/
```

[1]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

[2]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

[3]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

/public_html/index.php

if (!defined('ROOT')) {
define('ROOT', DS.'home'.DS. 'user');
}

/**
* The actual directory name for the "app".
*
*/
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
}
```

Comment: exactly which type of url you want please can you give me any demo url

Comment: The new url should be: www.domain.com/properties/view/1999

Comment: Nick want to confirm: you are passing URL www.domain.com/properties.aspx?prop=1999 and its redirecting to www.domain.com/properties, right?

Comment: Nick one more question that in public_html folder you have setup cakephp in any folder or in public_html folder itself?

Comment: Hi, yes that is correct any url from the internet with www.domain.com/properties.aspx?prop=1999 goes to www.domain.com/properties. CakePHP is installed above public_html  I suppose this can give confusion, so here is the real path /home/user/app  thus above /home/user/public_html I hope this is clear as some prefer to say below and others above :-)   /app and /public_html are at same level in tree. Everything works fine throughout the website, it is only this url what gives a lot of problems and my Google webmaster tools is full with errors.

Comment: Sadly my problem is not solved, but at least you both tried, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick I think its the problem due to .htaccess file

You have setup cakephp in public_html but I think you have replaced .htaccess file of cakephp which contains code like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

place this .htaccess file at out side the app folder,means in publich_html folder

Comment: Hiya, sorry but cakePHP is not installed in public_html it is at same level, i will put it up in my question as a graphic line.

Comment: Hi Er.KT I have put up the structure and contents of the the 3 .htaccess files. As well how the path is set in the index.php file. Thanks very much for helping in this

Comment: I noticed there was an update to v2.3.9 and I have applied it, but no difference.

Comment: Hi, a shame you didn't came back after me posting all .htaccess, I have a feeling you might be right somewhere as i can't add any other rule to the public_html .htaccess, I hope you come back and contact me.

Comment: Hey Nick am sorry but am not sure how to solve your problem,but I have doubt with your /public_html/.htaccess [3] file.so try remove all your code and check its working or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
Router::connect('properties/view/:id',
array('controller' => 'properties', 'action' => 'view'),
  array(
      'pass' => array('id')
  )
);
```

This 'id' will then be passed to 'view' function inside 'properties' controller as a parameter

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working, it shows all properties. This is url coming from: properties.aspx?prop=1999

Comment: hmm .. It should work .. Can you do some debugging? Make your view function as function view($id = null) { prd($id);...}  See if you are getting value of $id there.. If yes, then you will have to write logic to just send that value

Comment: instead of "id", maybe use "prop" then.

Comment: No result so far, I have put up the view function code, but as mentioned before it works perfect on the website, but the old urls got lost in wwww.domain.com/properties   Showing a list of all properties.

Answer (score 0):

Go for

```
Router::connect('/Properties/*',array('controller' => 'Properties', 'action' => 'view'),array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Comment: Sorry, this still goes to www.domain.com/properties    which of course shows all [paginated] properties and not the property with id 1999. Perhaps the .htaccess is a problem? I will add it to the question.

Comment: So please can you post htaccess in question